# Would moving the SQL Server of my TFS 2010 Server to a seperate machine mean I can update the cube more frequently?

Tags: team-foundation-server, sql-server

We currently update our analysis services cube every 15 min.  We want this closer to real time if possible.

We have our TFS Server and our SQL Server on the same machine.  If we split these to [use two machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404854.aspx), would the extra power of having two machines make it possible to lower the cube update without noticing a performance drop?  I would like to take it to around 2 min (or less if possible).

What do you think?  Would this work?  Or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

The answer is impossible for anyone but you to say.  Its completely dependent on the hardware involved and the load involved.

Buy big enough hardware (either two separate machines or one even bigger machine) and I'm sure you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also move analysis services to its own hardware for maximum power. If you look at the page you link, it says that dual-server means "two *or more*" servers. Topology is more flexible than ever before in tfs2010.